# Inequality for $|e^{-x}-e^{-y}|$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

What is the nicest upper bound we can have for
$$|e^{-x}-e^{-y}|,\quad x,y\in[0,\infty)$$
in terms of $|x-y|$?

Comment: Umm... $0$ maybe?

Comment: Haha.  Okay I edited it.  The nicest USEFUL bound.

Comment: @Harold, you are mistaken. It is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does "nicest" mean? The *strongest* is

$$1 - e^{-|x-y|}.$$

Certainly this bound is attained (when $x$ or $y$ is $0$), and the proof of it is straightforward: for $x\geq y$, say,

$$|e^{-x} - e^{-y}| = e^{-y} | 1 - e^{-(x-y)}| \leq |1 - e^{-(x-y)}|.$$

If "nicest" means "simplest" then $|x-y|$ is a good candidate, depending on context.

Answer (score 5):

From the Lagrange's mean value theorem we have
$$e^{-x}-e^{-y}=-e^{-\xi}(y-x),$$
where $\xi$ is between $x$ and $y.$ Therefore,
$$|e^{-x}-e^{-y}|=e^{-\xi}\cdot |y-x| \leqslant |x-y|$$
since $e^{-\xi} \leqslant {1}.$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lvert e^{-x} - e^{-y} \rvert = e^{-y} \lvert 1 - e^{- (x - y)} \rvert \le e^{-y}
$$
And a similar bound for $x$. In escence, $\max(e^{-x}, e^{-y})$ is the best you'll get. Or something like, for $y > x$:
$$
\lvert e^{-x} - e^{-y} \rvert \le e^{-y} (1 - e^{- \lvert x - y \rvert})
$$